# Редирект на страницу пользователя в зависимости от типа

Tags: php, редирект

В таблице с пользователями есть колонка type в которой всего 2 типа админ и юзер,ниже представленый код обработчика проверяет если это админ то редирект на  страницу admin.php если другой тип отличный от первого то на страницу user.php.Проблема в следующем при заходе под лог+пасс админа редирект есть а вот если тип user то выдает ошибку:

Нет контакта!

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\OSPanel\domains\regrole\do_login.php:24) in D:\OSPanel\domains\regrole\do_login.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OSPanel\domains\regrole\do_login.php:24) in D:\OSPanel\domains\regrole\do_login.php on line 22

```
    include('connect.php');
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $email=$_POST["txtemail"];
        $pass=$_POST["txtpass"];
    
        $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email,pass,type FROM users");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        
            $db_email=$row["email"];
            $db_pass=$row["pass"];
            $db_type=$row["type"];
            
            if($email==$db_email && $pass==$db_pass){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["email"]=$db_email;
                $_SESSION["type"]=$db_type;
                
                if($_SESSION["type"]=='admin'){
                    header("Location:admin.php");
                }
                else
                    header("Location:user.php");
            }else
                echo("Нет контакта!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Никакого вывода чего-либо до полной обработки. Для этого можно использовать ob_start(), ob_end_flush(), ob_flush() (За документацией в поисковики).
Остальное - обычный редирект с помощью header. И, кстати, header уже отправляет данные.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что заголовки уже были отправлены. Посмотри, есть ли вывод инфы (`echo`, `print` и т.п.) до `session_start()`;

И читай ошибки! Что у тебя в файле `do_login.php` на строках 14 и 24?

Comment: Нет ничего подобного до session_start(); нет, ни в инклюде ни в обработчике.14 стр. session_start(); 24 стр. echo("Нет контакта!"); Собственно код do_login.php  я и привел в пример это весь код